# Add Missing Rows in Financial Database

Tags: sql, mariadb, quantitative-finance

I have the following database from today's date going back to 1997. (snipping below)

```
# TIME               , OPEN      , HIGH     , LOW      , CLOSE    , VOLUME
'2016-09-22 21:00:00',  '1.30743', '1.30876', '1.29149', '1.29579', '168985'
'2016-09-20 21:00:00',  '1.29869', '1.29969', '1.29828', '1.29873', '764'
'2016-09-19 21:00:00',  '1.30275', '1.30648', '1.2947' , '1.29847', '201072'
'2016-09-18 21:00:00',  '1.29991', '1.3081' , '1.2996' , '1.30795', '142635'
'2016-09-15 21:00:00',  '1.32371', '1.32475', '1.2994' , '1.29958', '256907'
'2016-09-14 21:00:00',  '1.32318', '1.32784', '1.31791', '1.32371', '598912'
'2016-09-13 21:00:00',  '1.31879', '1.32404', '1.31381', '1.32318', '241908'
```

On closer inspection I have noticed there are missing data points. For instance in the snipping above 2016-09-21 21:00:00 is missing.

2016-09-16 21:00:00 and 2016-09-17 21:00:00 are missing also, however I am not concerned about those dates because they fall on the weekend.

I was thinking of using an average for the missing data. Some data points have 3 rows missing which complicates this further.

I thought maybe

```
(a + b) / (q+1) = x

a = data point after the missing row 
b = data point before the missing row 
q = amount of data points missing 
x = increment value
```

The outcome would be

```
# TIME               , OPEN      , HIGH     , LOW      , CLOSE    , VOLUME
'2016-09-22 21:00:00',  '1.30743', '1.30876', '1.29149', '1.29579', '168985'
'2016-09-21 21:00:00',  '1.30306', '1.30422', '1.29488', '1.29726', '85256'
'2016-09-20 21:00:00',  '1.29869', '1.29969', '1.29828', '1.29873', '764'
'2016-09-19 21:00:00',  '1.30275', '1.30648', '1.2947' , '1.29847', '201072'
'2016-09-18 21:00:00',  '1.29991', '1.3081' , '1.2996' , '1.30795', '142635'
'2016-09-15 21:00:00',  '1.32371', '1.32475', '1.2994' , '1.29958', '256907'
'2016-09-14 21:00:00',  '1.32318', '1.32784', '1.31791', '1.32371', '598912'
'2016-09-13 21:00:00',  '1.31879', '1.32404', '1.31381', '1.32318', '241908'
```

Is there method to find then add the missing rows to the database excluding Friday and Saturday using SQL code?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Is using something like PL/SQL an option?

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak Not sure, does PL/SQL work with MariaDB?

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle only; not MySQL/MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

How to do it:

- Use a [*MariaDB sequence*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/) to generate all dates.
- Add a `WHERE` clause to toss Sat/Sun.
- Do a `LEFT JOIN` to see which dates are missing.
- Worry about dates when the market was shutdown.
- Put the remaining dates into a temp table.
- Now, build an ugly query that joins from that temp table twice into the raw data in order to get the two rows, do the average and generate the fake data.
- Put that inside an `INSERT`.

Why not to do it:

Frankly, I think this is *wrong*.  You will now have a a table with some valid data and some estimated data.  Any user (including yourself) will be fooled into believing it is all valid data.  Please don't build such a "lie".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'll be easy to do it in a query. Unless performance is super important, I'd use the procedural language: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-procedure/

This'll let you do it in steps.

I don't have time to write out the entire query, but my suggestion would be to first generate a list of all dates since 1997 at 9pm, then filter that down to only ones that don't appear in the list. Then, for each, query the original table to generate the numbers you need. Then insert the entire list into your table.

Comment: How would I create a list of dates that include the US summer time 1 hour offset because not all rows are 21:00? Further down the list they change to 22:00